# C++ - fork() and its return value

Tags: c++, join, fork, wait

I'm having troubles with this simple exercise. Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
pid_t pid1,pid2,pid3;
int a=5,b=4,c=3,retval,retval2;
pid1=fork();
if(pid1==0){
    pid3=fork();
    if(pid3==0)
        exit(a);
    else if(pid3>0){
        waitpid(pid2,&retval2,0);
        cout<<WEXITSTATUS(retval2); 
    }
}
else if(pid1>0){
    pid2=fork();
    if(pid2==0){
        cout<<"CIAO";
        exit(b);
    }
    else if(pid2>0){
        waitpid(pid3,&retval,0);
        cout<<WEXITSTATUS(retval);
    }
}

return 0; }
```

As you can see it's not that complicated. All I want to do is pid2(father) to print pid3(son) return value and pid3(father) to print pid2(son) return value. Any advice? I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: A number of things are wrong: variables will be copied in their current state, but updates to those variables will not propagate across (e.g. changes to `pid2` will not be visible to any other processes, so your `wait(pid2)` won't work. Also, even if it did work, it'd be a race condition anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the first fork (the one that sets `pid1`), the second forks run in different processes.  In the `pid1==0` branch, `pid2` never gets a value, because that process never assigns it one.  Likewise, in the `pid1>0` branch, `pid3` never gets a value.

It looks like you're expecting the two processes to share the same set of variables, but it doesn't work like that.  Forking creates two independent processes, each with its own copy of all its variables.

Comment: And how should I proceed? I have to use just fork() and wait() (or waitpid()).

Comment: It's unclear how you should proceed because it's unclear what you're actually trying to accomplish. Why do your two processes need to know about each other's children? A process can't `waitpid` for a process that isn't it's own child anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In your program, *pid1* and *pid3* are children of the original process (let's call it *pid0*), *pid2* is the child of *pid1*.

Variables `pid1`, `pid2` etc are only updated in specific processes, and left unitialized in the others. Waiting for *pid3* in any other process than pid0 for instance does not make sense, because other processes won't have `pid3` correctly set. Furthermore, waiting for a process which isn't a child of the current process doesn't work.

Also, the  `wait` syscall takes a pointer as its parameter for the terminated child process return value. Doing a `wait(pid2)` is incorrect.

Now, to get the result you want, you'll have to set some kind of communication channel between *pid1* and *pid0*, so that they may transmit to each other the return code of their respective child. A `pipe` created in *pid0* might do the trick.

System call references:

- [wait](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait)
- [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe)